# What is the initialization {0} in C?

Tags: c

In a book I am reading the author has code `char initial[2] = {0};`
What does this mean? I didn't think char could be promoted also not to an int?

Comment: `char` is an integer type and can be assigned the value `0`. Also a character such as `'a'` is an `int` type, not `char`.

Comment: In C, `char` means 8-bit integer.

Comment: @Barmar - Not necessarily 8-bit; rather "_Smallest addressable unit of the machine that can contain basic character set._", but an integer nonetheless.   For TI C2000 DSP's for example a `char` is 16 bit because that is the smallest addressable unit in that architecture.

Comment: _"I didn't think char could be promoted also not to an int?"_ - it certainly can, but that has little to do with the question; nothing is being "promoted" here. Rather there is an _implicit conversion_ from int to char. In C a char is simply a "small" integer.

Comment: @Clifford If I were writing a full answer I would have said something like "at least 8-bit integer", I didn't feel the need to go into detail in a throwaway comment.

Comment: @Barmar It is possible to be both succinct and accurate.  The point would have been served perhaps simply by "char in an integer type” - size is irrelevant to the point you were making.